# Inferring the Kolmogorov complexity of a string from its substrings' complexity

Tags: co.combinatorics, kolmogorov-complexity

I know that the Kolmogorov complexity of a substring $v$ of an incompressible string $x$ has $C(v)\geq |v|-O(\log{|x|})$ , but I'm wondering if it is also possible to infer the complexity of a string given its substrings' complexity:

Specifically, If $x$ is a string of length $n$ and every substring $v$ of $x$ having length $m$ has complexity $C(v)\geq k$, is it possible to infer any general lower bound for $C(x)$ in terms of $n$, $m$, and $k$? I'm thinking that $C(x)$ cannot be much smaller than $k$ or else the $C(v)$ would not have $k$ as a lower bound. On the other hand, since $n$ can be much larger than $m$ this might balance things out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple bound is that we could use a program generating $x$, a starting index $1 \leq i \leq n$ and length $m$ to get a program generating any choice of $v$, and thus $C(v)$ is bounded as

$$\forall v: k \leq C(v) \leq C(x) + \log(n) + \log(m) + c,$$

where $c$ is some constant overhead independent from $x,v$ that represents the steps necessary to take a Turing machine, a starting index and length and return the requested substring.

This in turn gives us a lower bound for $C(x)$,

$$C(x)  \geq k - \log(n) - \log(m) - c.$$

Comment: Thanks. I thought though that a string always has a kolmogorov complexity at least as high as any of its substrings'. (In this case $C(x)\geq k$ without a need to subtract any more). Is that not necessarily true?

Comment: @Ari No. Consider a program that generates all strings up to length $n$ concatenated.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I also thought about it more and realized that without knowing any more about $x$, yours is about the best bound we can hope for. That is, if $x$ is $\frac{n}{m}$ copies of $v$ concatenated, we get $C(x)\leq k+O(\log(\frac{n}{m}))$.

Comment: @Ari I didn't claim my bound was the best possible, and your original question was more generic than copies of $v$ concatenated (the substrings could overlap in your original question). So I wouldn't be so quick with your conclusion.